# wget --accept-regex for url path matching?

Tags: wget

Is it possible to `wget` files matched with specific directory pattern?

For example, I want to download all the `.dsc` files form this site http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/. And only from sub directory `/libg/`.

```
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libgdsii/libgdsii_0.1+ds.1-1.dsc
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/libg/libgeotiff-epsg/libgeotiff-epsg_1.4.0-1.dsc
...
```

I tried this command but not working as expected.

```
wget -r -nH -np --accept-regex="\/libg\/.*\.dsc" -R index.htm* http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/
```